# "Failed to download repository information" after updating Ubuntu

Tags: update-manager, software-sources

I used the Software Updater and at the end it said

> **Failed to download repository information**
>   Check your Internet connection

[image: screenshot of popup]

I saw an article said use `sudo apt-get update`

I tried and it said

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://mirror.ehost.vn/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirror.ehost.vn/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirror.ehost.vn/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirror.ehost.vn/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Reading package lists... Done                          
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also saw a post saying that I should go to **Settings** and select **Select best server** in **Download from** in the **Ubuntu Software** tab.

However, when I closed that window this appeared:

[image: The information about available software is out of date]

I pressed <kbd>Reload</kbd> and it ran a cache update, but when it finished it again said

> **Failed to download repository information**
>   Check your Internet connection
>
> Details
>   `E:The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

My network is totally fine.